# NoSuchMethodError error when adding mahout as a dependency to maven project which is created with grizlly archetype

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jersey

I'm trying to write a maven project. Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sampleProjectName</name>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.17</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.project.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I used `jersey-quickstart-grizlly2 (2.17)` as archetype when I created maven project. Now when I run the main function. I got  these exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:122)
    at com.redis.ml.ws2.Main.startServer(Main.java:29)
    at com.redis.ml.ws2.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

However, when I remove the mahout dependency my project works properly. Unfortunately I need mahout for my project. How could I run these together?

***EDIT***

I saw that this error may be result of having two different versions of the class on class path. Since error caused by mahout dependency, I checked its dependencies.  [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.9/META-INF/maven/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/pom.xml?av=f) as you can see there is no com.sun.jersey record. So what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you're right, it is a conflict of Major versions. If you run `mvn dependency:tree` you will see the following

```
...
[INFO]    \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO]       +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]       +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]       +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
...
```

`hadoop-core` pulls in `jersey-core:1.8`, which is the culprit. It packages JAX-RS core classes into it's jar. If you look in the jar, you will see the core packages

- `javax.ws.rs`
- `javax.ws.rs.core`
- `javax.ws.rs.ext`

I don't really see much option but to switch to using Jersey 1.x. 1.8 is pretty old, and Jersey is still pushing out releases on the 1.x line (1.19) is the latest. So if you want a newer version, you can try to use 1.19 and see if it is compatible with the Hadoop dependency. I can't say for sure. But still, if you are looking for 2.x features, I don't think you're going to get it, if the Hadoop is required.

I did some playing around trying to use 1.19, which does not include the JAX-RS classes in it's jar, and see if I could exclude the JAX-RS 1.x jar and hope that the JAX-RS 2.x jar would be backward compatible but it doesn't look like it.

So the only option I see is to just use 1.x. I can see you are using the Jersey archetype. There is also an archetype for the 1.x line

```
groudId:     com.sun.jersey.archetypes
artifactId:  jersey-quickstart-grizzly2  
version:     1.x
```

That's all I really have for you :(

Here is the [1.x documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html).